# Proof Involving Binomial Coefficients

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

Can someone please help me prove the below identity:

$$
\sum_{r=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}
\binom{n-r}{r} \left(\frac12\right)^{n-r}
=
\frac13 \left\lbrace 2 + \frac{(-1)^n}{2^n}\right\rbrace
$$

I came across this series while solving the below question:
A player tosses a coin and scores one point for every head and two points for every tail that turns up. Find the probability that he/she scores exactly 'n' points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a recurrence.
The formula is true for $n=0$ and $n=1$.
Assume $X_{2n} = 1/3(2+1/2^{2n})$ and $X_{2n+1} = 1/3(2-1/2^{2n+1})$ for a specific $n\in \mathbb{N}$.
Then show, using Pascal binomial formula, that $1/2(X_{2n+1}+X_{2n}) = X_{2n+2}$. Similarly for $X_{2n+3}$. The result follows.